# Generate SHA-256 hash for a XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, hash, sha256

I'm trying to add a caching feature for http requests  (for one of my projects) and I thought of using Etag as the hash value. But if the Etag is not there i thought of using the payload to generate a unique hash value. As we all know same xml pay loads might have different structures. For example ***Sample A and Sample B are same***. But their string structures are not the same. What I need is a way to generate the same hash key from both xml samples.

**Sample A**

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**Sample B**

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: If order is unimportant in your application, you should normalise the structures to some canonical order, and then hash that.

Comment: Normalizing XML that way is a lot of work. See the standards for Digitally Signed XML. But why does this happen in your application? How come the server produces XML that is semantically equivalent but looks totally different?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have tried to normalize the XML document with `org.w3c.dom.document.normalizeDocument()` method but each time I normalize the Document it doesn't consider the structure of the object. So still I can't get a unique hash for two XML payloads with the two different structures.

Comment: @Thilo I use the request payload as the hash value to cache the response. Request is generated from the client side. So in some cases this scenario can occur.

Comment: That isn't going to alter the order of elements, because it doesn't know that order is unimportant in your application.

Comment: I'd actually recommend not bothering.  My feeling is that it won't actually be a problem because the XML is going to be created by software and the software is likely to generate XML with the same element order.  If there are a few odd cases that probably won't impact on cache performance *significantly*.  (Insert standard advice about premature optimization.)

Comment: Sample A and Sample B are *not* the same as far as XML is concerned.  Your application might consider them equivalent, but XML does not.  So whatever normalization you do is going to be application-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.w3c.dom.document.normalizeDocument()` document does not alter the order of child elements.

You *could* do this by a recursive parse of the document. However, consider whether this is more expensive than the operation you're trying to cache in the first place...

Method

- At each level copy all the nodes to a `java.util.List` implementation, i.e. ArrayList. This is required because org.w3c.dom.NodeList does not allow modification
- Sort the list using `Collections.sort()`
- Remove children from their parent
- Add children back in sorted order

*Note this does not deal with multiple elements of same name with different contents, but does solve your example*

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("test.xml"));
    sort(doc);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));

    System.out.println(writer);
}

private static void sort(Node doc) {
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
        children.add(doc.getChildNodes().item(i));
    }
    for (Node child : children) {
        doc.removeChild(child);
    }
    Collections.sort(children, (a, b) -> {
        return a.getNodeName().compareTo(b.getNodeName());
    });
    for (Node child : children) {
        doc.appendChild(child);
    }
    for (Node child : children) {
        sort(child);
    }
}
```